# Node js: getting error "listener must be a function"

Tags: node.js, listener

i've this code:

```
function myfunction(url_parts){
  fs.unlink(__dirname + '/temp/' + url_parts + '.pdf', function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('unlink ok');
  });
}
var url_parts= 'filename'
req.on("close", myfunction(url_parts));
```

I get error "listener must be a function". But myfunction is a function :D what's wrong??
**I don't get this error if i don't pass any param** to myfunction, but i need to pass url_parts.
I can't use anonymous function because i need to call removeListener method in another part of the code.

```
req.removeListener('close', myfunction);
```

Comment: Try `req.removeAllListeners('close');`.

Comment: no, the error is here --> req.on("close", myfunction(url_parts));

Comment: If `req` is an extension of `EventEmitter` then you can use an anonymous function there and use `req.removeAllListeners('close');` to remove the listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function (Assigned to the Function.prototype). Your code will become (Changing the last line only)

```
function myfunction(url_parts){
  fs.unlink(__dirname + '/temp/' + url_parts + '.pdf', function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('unlink ok');
  });
}
var url_parts= 'filename'
req.on("close", myfunction.bind(null, url_parts));
```

The bind function allows you to create a new function which will pass the arguments you define when calling bind to the function everytime it is called in the future.

To remove the event later, you should remove the result of the bind call, not the original function.

Comment: Sorry but I saw this reply after 3 years. This is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK anything that uses events in Node.js are extended on EventEmitter.

You could try using an anonymous function to add the listener, and to remove it:

```
req.removeAllListeners('close');
```

Comment: merging your answer (removealllistener) with Salem's answer (calling myfunction inside an anonymous function) i solved my problem :D